# Alternative for nested lists in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I use Python to build a tool that can group neighboring pixels.

First, from the raw output (.txt file) I create a NumPy array (pixeldata) with ID, x, y, and t on each row.

```
# id x y  t 
1   12 15 125
2   12 14 127
3   11 14 128
4   54 87 212
5   11 15 315
....
```

Then I start looking for neighboring pixels (as well in time as in space) and store them in a list. This list gets appended to the cluster list, below the (simplified version) of the algorithm. Of course, I keep track of already used pixels and do not loop twice over the same particles.

```
clusters = []
used_pixels = []

for i in range():
  if i in used_pixels:
    pass  # pixel already considered
  else:
    
    current_cluster = [[pixeldata[i,:]]
    t_start = pixeldata[i,3]
    current_index = -1
    while current_index < len(current_cluster):
      current_index += 1
      start_index = i - 100  # order is not 100% chronological so go back in time a little bit.
    if start_index < 0: start_index = 0
    for j in range(start_index, len(pixeldata)):
      if i == j or j in usedpixels:
        pass
      else:
        time_difference = pixeldata[j,3] - t_start
        if time_difference > max_time_dif:
          break
        if abs(time_difference) < time_window:
          distance = np.sqrt(  (pixdat[i, 1] - pixdat[j, 1]) * (pixdat[i, 1] - pixdat[j, 1]) + (pixdat[i, 2] - pixdat[j, 2]) * (pixdat[i, 2] - pixdat[j, 2]))
          if distance <= pixel_range:
            current_cluster.append([id, x, y])
            used_pixels.append(pixeldata[j,0])
    clusters.append(current_cluster)
```

The algorithm itself works fine, but it becomes slow at larger datasets. The problem is probably that I use a nested list and the need to reallocate memory.

Neighboring pixels are grouped in a cluster. So as a result I get:

```
[ 
  [ [x1,y1], [x2,y2], [x3,y3] ],
  [ [x4,x5], [x5,y5] ]
]
```

This list contains clusters, and each cluster is a list of pixel coordinates.

Is there any way I can obtain a similar result, but I don't have to use the .append() function? Or any ideas to speed this up?

Comment: Do the operations using vectorized numpy operations than loops. You need to post more of your code if you need help with that.

Comment: Oddly shaped numpy arrays dont perform as well as regular numpy arrays. A good middle ground is to use a list of numpy arrays. That way you can use the append function as well as keep decent performance. Do note that a lot of it depends on the algorithm itself.

Comment: Please always post minimal, working, complete and reproducible code if you want help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You can check out the guidelines here. The thing is, If you do not format your questions in such a manner that it makes easy for people to just copy paste your code and try to fix the issue that you are having, they are simply going to move on to the next question.

Comment: If you just need an efficient list data type, you can use [the standard library's `array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html).